# Submit outlook addin for unknown release date

Tags: office-store

I've been asked by a manager to find out if you can you submit an outlook addin to the store to get approval but then go live at a point you don't know on submission?

i.e. we know roughly when we want to release but not the exact date and want to get approval now so if we want to go live with it we can just make the call on a particular day and have it 'pre-approved'

I don't think this is possible but just looking for confirmation and this page... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-the-office-store says...

If you have questions about policies or requirements in your report, you can engage with the AppSource Valdidation Team via Stack Overflow. Tag your question with "Office-Store"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the release date for your add-in when editing the listing in the SellerDashboard. The date you choose as Start Date will be the date the add-in is released on. If you do not enter a value in this field, the add-in will go live once approved. 
It's not possible to have a variable release date.

Our suggestion would be to set a release date far in the future and submit your add-in. This will allow it to be published and hidden once it passes validation. Once you have then decided on the release date required you can update your listing on SellerDashboard and resubmit to validation. (Note this would still go through the validation process, so same day publishing is highly unlikely)